# Run Windows Explorer on remote system from its cygwin shell through SSH

Tags: windows, shell, ssh, cygwin, windows-explorer

Please consider my problem :)

1) I Have a Windows 7 - x64 system with cygwin installed and SSHD running.
2) From another Windows machine , from futty, SSH to the above machine.
3) Command "TaskKill /IM explorer.exe /F" to kill explorer. **Success**!
4) Command "/cygdrive/c/Windows/sysnative/cmd.exe /c start /B explorer.exe" to start explorer.  **Failed**!!
 
From task manager I can see that the explorer process is running, but no visible "proof" for it. No icons , No task bar.
5) (optional) Command "ps -W | grep explorer | cut -c 31-36 | paste -s -d," to see running explorer process Id from cygwin shell itself.

After searching google and StackOverFlow, the command mentioned in step 4 worked manually on direct cygwin shell on target system.

Primary::
My question here is, is there any command to replace in Step 4, so that we have a "neat" Windows Explorer process up and running ?!

Secondary::
My aim is to remotely kill and start windows explorer properly, Any methods for doing it ?!

Advanced Thanks!
 - Rx3 -